videojs handle seekbar width
Need to customize the video js seekBar
I'm working on a project using Video.js where I need to start a video from a specific time, effectively making that the new "0" point for the video.
Example:
The user uploads a video file that is 2 minutes long.
I want the video to start playing from 30 seconds, so I'm using player.currentTime(30) in the player.ready event.
Issue:
I want this 30-second mark to be reflected as the new starting point on the seek bar and the time displayed in the control bar.
I tried updating the seek bar width and the time in the timeupdate event, but Video.js seems to override my changes, causing a flickering issue.
Question:
How can I set a new start time (e.g., 30 seconds) and ensure that this is consistently reflected across the seek bar and time display without flickering?
